# How to control radio buttons? data echoed from database, PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button, controls

I am having a problem on sorting out the radio button while creating attendance interface for the teachers. I'm trying to get the right radio button checked when I pull data from a mysql database to display in an edit form.

There is a table of four columns where the columns are separated as names, present, absent and late. The list of names are echoed out in the webpage by fetching MYSQL database that means if a new student is added in the list then it will be echoed in the webpage along with the absent, present and late option automatically. Please have a look at the code below which I have used to echo out the list of names and other options individually.

```
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
           {

   echo "<tr>
   <td><img......../></td> 
   <td>" .$row['name']. $row['surname']."</td>  
   <td><input type='radio' name='attend' value='present' /> Present &nbsp;
   <input type='radio' name='attend' value='absent' /> Absent &nbsp;
   <input type='radio' name='attend' value='late' /> Late &nbsp; 
   <td>
    </tr>";
    }

   echo "<input class='attendanceSubmitBtn' type='submit' name='btnSubmit' value='Submit'>"; 
   echo "</table>"; 
   echo "</form> <br/>"; 
   ?>
```

To operate function

```
 foreach ($_POST['attend'] as $attendance => $value) {

 if($value == 'present') {

  $query = "INSERT INTO Test (date, status) VALUES (NOW(), '1')";  
   $close = mysqli_query($con, $query); 
  echo "present done properly";
```

Comment: you do not need an array for radio buttons because the user can select only one option. so `name="attend"` is the first edit you should make

Comment: @zeeks, Thanks I have tried your solution but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are displaying it wrongly. You need to provide different name for each attendance.

Do it like this:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
           {

   echo "<tr>
   <td><img......../></td> 
   <td>" .$row['name']. $row['surname']."</td>  
   <td><input type='radio' name='attend".$row['name']."' value='present' /> Present &nbsp;
   <input type='radio' name='attend".$row['name']."' value='absent' /> Absent &nbsp;
   <input type='radio' name='attend".$row['name']."' value='late' /> Late &nbsp; 
   <td>
    </tr>";
    }

   echo "<input class='attendanceSubmitBtn' type='submit' name='btnSubmit' value='Submit'>"; 
   echo "</table>"; 
   echo "</form> <br/>"; 
   ?>
```

As you can see I replaced `name='attend'` with `name='attend".$row['name']."'` but to make it even better you should replace the `$row['name']` there with a unique id, like primary key.

When you need to loop through all attend values you will need to loop through all names.

```
    foreach ($names as $name)
    {
    $value=$_POST['attend'.$name]; //this value could be absent , present or late
echo $name.' '.$value.'<br>'; //You have the name as well as value. Now you can insert or Update them in the database within this loop itself.
    }
```

But **again I strongly suggest you to use a primary key instead of name there.** Else you will have problems when names are same for two persons.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The first works fine which populate the radio buttons however since there was change I had to change my foreach as well. can you please explain a bit so that I can catch with the new foreach function.

Comment: $names is an array of all the names. You can get this from the first code's while loop, I posted, itself. while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $names[]=$row['name']; } This will create the $names array which you can use in the foreach loop. Once you get the $names array from that while loop you can use my foreach loop as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think we're missing quite a bit of information to properly help you, but I hope you can use this bit of code I've put together for you. Assuming that the 'status' in the database for present is 1 (as seen in your example), for absent it's 2, and for late it's 3. Also I assume that your query on the top of your result contains this status somehow. Also, I've created a form for each table row, because I haven't seen any teacher ID to assign an array to the checkboxes' name tags.

Your PHP code to process the form:

```
<?php
if ($isset($_POST['attend']) {
  switch ($_POST['attend']) {
    case 'present':
      $status = 1;
      break;
    case 'absent':
      $status = 2;
      break;
    case 'late':
      $status = 3;
      break;
    default:
      $status = 0;
      break;
  }
  if ($status != 0) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO Test (date, status) VALUES (NOW(), " . $status . ")";
    $close = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    echo $_POST['attend'] . " done properly";
  }
}
?>
```

Your form (I guess you have an opening `<table>` tag and a table header somewhere before this):

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query(" WHATEVER YOUR QUERY IS ");

$statuses = array(1 => 'Present', 2 => 'Absent', 3 => 'Late');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><img......../></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['surname']; ?></td>  
    <td>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <?php foreach ($statuses as $status) { ?>
        <input type="radio" name="attend" value="<?php echo strtolower($status); ?>"<?php echo ($row['status'] == $status) ? ' checked' : ''; ?> /> <?php echo $status; ?> &nbsp;
      <?php } ?>
      <input class='attendanceSubmitBtn' type='submit' name='btnSubmit' value='Submit'> 
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the when copied second PHP code, it shows error because the php open and close is not inserted properly.

Comment: It was just a guideline, on how to dynamically create radio buttons. I didn't know how the rest of your code look like, so it wasn't meant to be a "copy-paste" solution. I just wanted to point you in an appropriate direction.